# how to add new filter operator to telerik radgridview in windows form

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik, radgridview

I want to add new filter operator for string values in Telerik Radgridview control. also I want to set this new operator as default operator for string values.

how can i do this? if you can help me. i appreciate your helps.

thank you.

Comment: Please can you share the code that you have so far and tell us what it is that is missing when you run said code?

Answer (score 0):

RadGridView is designed to provide the appropriate filter operators according to the stored data type in the respective column. Hence, the different column types offer different filter operators: https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/controls/gridview/filtering/filtering-row
It would be great if you share what filter operator is missing and what is the value type that you store in the column. Thus, we would get better understanding of the precise case and think about an appropriate solution.

Meanwhile, you can consider using the customer filtering functionality that RadGridView offers. It is a flexible mechanism for filtering RadGridView rows by using custom logic: https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/controls/gridview/filtering/custom-filtering

I hope this information helps.